# Small Text file File upload HTML to PHP stopped working on upgrade to php 5.4 from 5.3

Tags: php, html, upload

I have just been forced to upgrade from php 5.3 to 5.4  The file upload mechanism has stopped working.  I only need to upload one file at a time.  Each file is just a simple .txt file of less than 20kBytes in size.

As far as I can see the filename is not being passed to php from the HTML form.

```
<FORM name="form2" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php">
  <P><STRONG>Upload log file:</STRONG> 
    <INPUT name="call" type="hidden" value="<? echo $call; ?>">
    <INPUT name="logfile" type="file">
    <INPUT type="submit" name="Submit2" value="Send file">
  </P>
</FORM>


    $logfile = $_GET[logfile];
    echo "<P>" .$logfile. " for ".$call."</P>\n";
    if ($logfile == "none") {
        echo "<P>No file uploaded.</P>\n";
        exit;
        }
    echo "<P>File " .$logfile_name." uploaded, ".$logfile_size." bytes.</P>\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

In index.html

```
<FORM name="form2" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php">
  <P><STRONG>Upload log file:</STRONG> 
    <INPUT name="call" type="hidden" value="<? echo $call; ?>">
    <INPUT name="logfile" type="file">
    <INPUT type="submit" name="Submit2" value="Send file">
  </P>
</FORM>
```

in upload.php

```
<?php
$logfile = $_FILES['logfile']['name'];
    echo "<P>" .$logfile. "</P>\n";
    if ($logfile == "") {
        echo "<P>No file uploaded.</P>\n";
        exit;
        }
    echo "<P>File " .$logfile." uploaded, ".$_FILES['logfile']['size']." bytes.</P>\n";
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_FILES);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Sorry - this hasn't worked.  I'm not seeing any signs of the file to be uploaded being recognised by the php code.

Comment: ````$logfile = $_GET[logfile];```` to ````$logfile = $_FILES['logfile']['name'];````

Comment: Sorry this hasn't worked either.  I'm still not seeing any signs of the file to be uploaded being recognised by the php code.

Comment: I'm starting to home in on the problem.  With the recent move to php 5.4 from 5.3 safe mode has been disabled.  If I place the file in the same the directory on the server from where the php runs, I can read the file.  However I am not able to 'transfer' a file using HTML form - if I do, PHP say the file doesn't exist.